# Назначить адрес функции

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. В Delphi функции, описанной в VAR, можно присвоить адрес, что-то вроде такого:

@func1 := Pointer($00112233);

Как то же самое делается в C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель на функцию, принимающую аргумент double и возвращающую double.

```
double (*funct)(double) = (double(*)(double))(0x00111);
```

Дальше работать как с обычным указателем на функцию.
Вариант с typedef`ом

```
typedef double(*ptr)(double);
//некий код
ptr funct = reinterpret_cast<ptr>(0x00111); //можно и обычным приведением типов, как выше было.
```